# the resource cannot be found when trying to access forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, web-config, forms-authentication

Trying to test forms authentication and when i put 4 aspx pages in a seperate folder and in the web.config file I entered  and when I open the page outside the folder and try to redirect to the page inside i should be practically go to the login page as per form authorization.I have attached a screenshot below let me know if you need any more information.

http://postimg.org/image/bzqtfnt0d/ error page

http://postimg.org/image/84nfd39ul/ code for redirect

http://postimg.org/image/gobeol7kt/ solution explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this `Response.Redirect("~/Secured/edituser.aspx");`